# How to get a list of dates in between 2 dates per ID? SQL BigQuery

Tags: sql, loops, date, google-bigquery

I need to find a way to get a list of dates that are between 2 dates.

There is a table called 'stores' and in this table, there is an OpenDate and a CloseDate. See example below. Example data in 'DD/MM/YYYY' format.

**CURRENT**

| StoreID | OpenDate | CloseDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 02/04/2023 |
| 102 | 28/04/2023 | 20/05/2023 |
| 103 | 14/10/2022 | 30/03/2023 |

What I need to achieve, is to get a list of all months/dates where the Store was active. I am hoping to then get a table looking like the below where the StoreID becomes a MANY relationship with multiple rows per StoreID.
The day in the date is not important.

**DESIRED**

| StoreID | OpenDate | CloseDate | ActiveDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 02/04/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 02/04/2023 | 01/02/2023 |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 02/04/2023 | 01/03/2023 |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 02/04/2023 | 01/04/2023 |
| 102 | 28/04/2023 | 20/05/2023 | 01/04/2023 |
| 102 | 28/04/2023 | 20/05/2023 | 01/05/2023 |
| 103 | 14/10/2022 | 30/03/2023 | 01/10/2022 |
| 103 | 14/10/2022 | 30/03/2023 | 01/11/2022 |
| 103 | 14/10/2022 | 30/03/2023 | 01/12/2022 |
| 103 | 14/10/2022 | 30/03/2023 | 01/01/2023 |
| 103 | 14/10/2022 | 30/03/2023 | 01/02/2023 |
| 103 | 14/10/2022 | 30/03/2023 | 01/03/2023 |

I am using Google BigQuery.

I tried using a Recursive CTE but there is a limit of 500 and there are thousands of StoreID's. I believe I need a WHILE or LOOP but unsure on the syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY() function to create an array of active dates for each store, then flatten the array with UNNEST() function + CROSS JOIN to merge it back to the original table:

```
WITH sample_table AS (
SELECT '101' as StoreID, DATE '2023-01-01' as OpenDate, DATE '2023-04-02' as CloseDate UNION ALL
SELECT '102' as StoreID, DATE '2023-04-28' as OpenDate, DATE '2023-05-20' as CloseDate UNION ALL
SELECT '103' as StoreID, DATE '2022-10-14' as OpenDate, DATE '2023-03-30' as CloseDate
)
SELECT *
FROM sample_table
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(
  DATE_TRUNC(OpenDate , month),
  DATE_TRUNC(CloseDate, month),
  INTERVAL 1 month)) as ActiveDate
```

I have used a little different DATE format for simplicity but let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: Thank you that's worked as I wanted it to!